# Compact and open sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

How to solve this question?

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $\{K_n\}$ a familly of decreasing compact non empty compact sets, Let $K=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} K_n$ and let $\Omega$ be an open set $$K\subset \Omega\Rightarrow \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, K_n\subset \Omega$$.

If I suppose by contradiction that $K\subset \Omega$ and $$\forall n_0\in\mathbb{N},\exists n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq n_0 ~\text{and}~ K_n\not\subset \Omega$$.

That is

$$\forall n_0\in\mathbb{N},\exists n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq n_0, \exists x\in K_n ~\text{and}~ x\in E\setminus \Omega$$

How to continue? Is there any other method?

Comment: It suffices to find *one* $n_0$ with $K_{n_0} \subseteq \Omega$, then the same will hold for all $K_n$ with $n \ge n_0$ by decreasingness.

Answer (score 1):

If **not**, then we have an open set $\Omega$ containing $K$ such that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: K_n \nsubseteq \Omega$$

and then we can thus define $C_n = K_n\setminus \Omega = K_n \cap( X\setminus \Omega)$ and all $C_n$ are non-empty (by the non-inclusion) and decreasing (as the $K_n$ are) and compact, $C_n$ being closed in $K_n$.

But then $\cap_n C_n \neq \emptyset$ by a standard fact on families of closed sets (by Hausdorffness of $X$) with the f.i.p. in a compact space ($C_0$).
But any $p \in \cap_n C_n$ is in all $K_n$, hence in $K$, but not in $\Omega$ contradiction.

Comment: where is $n_0$ ? whay you have $\forall n$??

Comment: see my edit @Henno Brandsma

Comment: @PolineSandra Because if the $K_n$ are decreasing, if you have an $n_0$ with $K_{n_0} \subseteq \Omega$ we automatically have that all $K_n$ with larger index are a subset too: $K_n \subseteq K_{n_0}$. So **one** $K_n$ inside $\Omega$ suffices, and my proof starts from the contrary assumption (**no** $K_n$ is) etc.

Comment: my problem is why you write $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, K_n\not\subset \Omega$$ by contradiction we have $\forall n_0\in\mathbb{N}, \exists n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: we have $\exists n_0 , \forall n$ so the negation is $\forall n_0,\exists n$

Comment: @PolineSandra $\exists n_0 \forall n \ge n_0$ is the same as $\exists n_0$ here. So only one quantifier needed.

Comment: i don't understand you start by $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, K_n\not\subset\Omega$ after that you say $\exists n_0 \forall n\geq n_0$ is the same $\exists n_0$ ?????

Comment: @PolineSandra Do you understand the comment on your question? You have to use the $K_n$ are decreasing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78659/discussion-between-poline-sandra-and-henno-brandsma).

Comment: Can we prove it using sequences ?

Comment: @PolineSandra not really. And sequences are not sufficient in general spaces anyway.

Comment: I found a proof on a book by sequences , $(x_n)\subset K_n$ then it has a convergent subsequence and it limits $x\in K$ then $x\in \Omega$ but $x\in X\setminus \Omega$ because $X\setminus\Omega$ is closed contradiction

Comment: @PolineSandra a compact space need not be sequentially compact. So that step already fails.

Comment: ??????????????????????????

Comment: @PolineSandra you’re not making sense. Study my proof and see that it works.

Comment: each sequence in a compact set has a convergent subsequence

Comment: @PolineSandra that is only true in some spaces, like sequential ones, not in all compact spaces!